# iteration through datagrid rows for export to excel (again)

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

I am trying to export dataGrid rows to an Excel sheet.
Since I am switching from a WinForms(dataGridView) to WPF
(dataGrid) and basically I have no clue about WPF so far
I need your help.

Maybe somebody can either tell me how to change my loop
or what I have to do instead to get the rows filled into
the cells of the Excel sheet.

I have read all articles on SO covering this problem but
don't seem to find a topic suiting my issue.

This is what I did for the filling of the column names, which
works perfectly:

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGrid.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    Excel.Range BackgroundColor;
    BackgroundColor = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("a9", "j9");
    BackgroundColor.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue);

    AxlEx.Cells[9, i] = dataGrid.Columns[i - 1].Header;
}
```

when it comes down to the filling of the cells with rows I have tried numerous attemps to get it working

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DataRowView aux = (DataRowView)dataGrid.Items[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < aux.Row.ItemArray.Length; j++)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}-{1}", j, aux.Row.ItemArray[j]));
        AxlEx.Cells[i + 10, j + 1] = aux.Row.ItemArray[j];
    }
}
```

throws me an exception of System.InvalidCast exception for a type mismatch 
which is obvious... but I don't know how to convert, here also the fitting
Topics on SO didn't have an example which i could understand to change my code.

Before I had this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGrid.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        AxlEx.Cells[i + 10, j + 1] = dataRow.Row.ItemArray[j].ToString();
    }
}
```

which then works for 1 row if i refer to

```
DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)dataGrid.SelectedItem;
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: what is your `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid`? `ObservableCollection<T>` or `DataTable`?

Comment: Hello StepUp its a DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know whether it is necessary to debug your code. However, I would like to show my work code to export data from `DataGrid` to `MS Excel`:

It is better to transfer this work from UI Thread to a `ThreadPool`:

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;//add this library

 Task.Run(() => {                    
                // load excel, and create a new workbook
                Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

                // single worksheet
                Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

                // column headings
                for (int i = 0; i < YourDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = YourDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                }

                // rows
                for (int i = 0; i < YourDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // to do: format datetime values before printing
                    for (int j = 0; j < YourDataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = YourDataTable.Rows[i][j];
                    }
                }
                excelApp.Visible = true;
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem....

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count-1; i++)
            {
                DataRowView aux = (DataRowView)dataGrid.Items[i];

                for (int j = 0; j < aux.Row.ItemArray.Length; j++)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}-{1}", j, aux.Row.ItemArray[j]));
                    AxlEx.Cells[i + 10, j + 1] = aux.Row.ItemArray[j];
                }
            }
```

i had to substract (dataGrid.Items.Count-1) because there was an additional blank line in the dataGrid which seemed to cause the problem.
Pobably due to a NULL field return value ??? 
the datagrid